# How do I replicate the _id and _type of elasticsearch index when dumping data through Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have an "Index":samcorp with "type":"sam".

One of them looks like the below :

```
{
  "_index": "samcorp",
  "_type": "sam",
  "_id": "1236",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "name": "Sam Smith",
    "age": 22,
    "confirmed": true,
    "join_date": "2014-06-01"
  }
}
```

I want to replicate the same data into a different "index" name "jamcorp" with the same "type" and same "id"

I am using Logstash to do it:

I use the below code in the configuration file of logstash I end up having wrong ids and type

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]     
   index => "samcorp"
  }
}
filter {
 mutate {
  remove_field => [ "@version", "@timestamp" ]
 }
}
output {
 elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
   manage_template => false
   index => "jamcorp"
   document_type => "%{_type}"
   document_id => "%{_id}"
 }
}
```

I've tried all possible combinations, I gt the following output:

Output:

```
{
  "_index": "jamcorp",
  "_type": "%{_type}",
  "_id": "%{_id}",
  "_version": 4,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "name": "Sam Smith",
    "age": 22,
    "confirmed": true,
    "join_date": "2014-06-01"
  }
}
```

The Ouptut I require is:

```
{
  "_index": "jamcorp",
  "_type": "sam",
  "_id": "1236",
  "_version": 4,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "name": "Sam Smith",
    "age": 22,
    "confirmed": true,
    "join_date": "2014-06-01"
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `elasticsearch` input, you need to set the [`docinfo` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-inputs-elasticsearch-docinfo) to `true`

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]     
   index => "samcorp"
   docinfo => true                            <--- add this
  }
}
```

As a result the `@metadata` hash will be populated with the `index`, `_type` and `_id` of the document and you can reuse that in your filters and outputs:

```
output {
 elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
   manage_template => false
   index => "jamcorp"
   document_type => "%{[@metadata][_type]}"   <--- use @metadata
   document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"       <--- use @metadata
 }
}
```